# Is there an equivalent to "big pi" for tensor products?

Tags: symbols

I'd like to be able to rewrite expressions like

```
$$[f(i,j,k,\ldots)]^{\otimes n}$$
```

in a form analogous to

```
$$\prod_{j\in J}f(i,j,k,\ldots)$$
```

so that I can distinguishing the index being varied and specify its domain.

Is there a notation for tensor products that corresponds to `$\prod$`?

Comment: How about $\bigotimes$, that is \bigotimes? To use it in a sentence, I guess:
$$
\bigotimes_{j\in J} f_j
$$

Comment: @FrankMcGovern: That looks like an answer! But (I know this is more $\LaTeX$ than math), how do I get under it to write the index?

Comment: This was migrated from math.se; do you think it was the right thing to do?

Comment: @egreg: I'd have left it in Math.SE (the question is about notation) and asked the $\LaTeX$ question separately here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll just give the answer here. The `\bigotimes` notation works great.

```
\bigotimes_{j\in J}\,f_j
```

Comment: +1. This notation is standard in the quantum information community.